# Isolated storage access permissions

Tags: .net, permissions, isolatedstorage

I have an application that stores some data in isolated storage. The data is stored with the Machine-Assembly scope so that all users on the given machine could access this data.

Everything seemed to work just fine under admin account, but as soon as we've tested our app under guest account we've run into user permission restrictions. It seems that isolated storage, being just a simple folder generated by the OS, can have some restrictions on user access to these folder.

In my case guest account by default had read/write permissions set, but as soon as we tried to delete a file that was placed in the storage under admin account we've run into an exception since guest account didn't have rights to delete files created by another user.

As a result we get a crash each time guest tries to use some of the features in the app that require deletion of the files created by another user.

I thought that perhaps I could try to check what permissions guest has prior to trying to proceed with deletion and warn him that he can not use these features since he doesn't have enough rights, but since the path to the isolated storage is generated by the OS and there is no way to find it out (other than doing a full traversal of the file system), so there's no way to check what rights guest account has.

Perhaps someone has any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Why does the guest need to delete files created by other users?

Answer (score 0):

*since the path to the isolated storage is generated by the OS and there is no way to find it out*

There is, but you'll have to use reflection. This is what I use (in this case a user store but the idea is the same):

```
string path;
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileNamePlusExtension, FileMode.Create, isf))
    {
      stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
      FieldInfo pi = stream.GetType().GetField("m_FullPath", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      path = pi.GetValue(stream).ToString();
    }
}
```

I dont't know why there's not a built-in way to get to such a file, maybe in the future.

Maybe you can create the file and then set the permissions for the guest account.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm willing to rely on a private variable. Thats somewhat risky and is definitely not the kind of hack I would like to ship with the product. What bothers me the most is that ,from what I've encountered on the web, isolated storage is supposed to be a safe location to store files with low trust privileges, which is why it is extensively used by Silverlight applications that need to store data on the user end, yet somehow it turned out to be a wrong assumption.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. For us, it was the only way to safely store a file temporarily under Windows7 and then use it for various purposes. Having to use hacks always makes me suspicious of design flaws in my code, but we just didn't find an better way.