# How to get path of isolated storage in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage, lync-2013, isolatedstoragefile

I read a similar post [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282569/isolated-storage-access-permissions/22896327#22896327). I tried implementing it but getting an exception saying

```
Attempt by method 'get_path_isolated.Page.button1_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)' to access field 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream.m_FullPath' failed.
```

I have this code

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    isoStore.CreateDirectory("root_dir");
    IsolatedStorageFileStream iostream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("sampleFile.txt", FileMode.Create, isoStore);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(iostream);
    writer.Write("jaimokar");

    try
    {
        FieldInfo pi = iostream.GetType().GetField("m_FullPath", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        string path = pi.GetValue(iostream).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textBox1.Text += ex.Message;
    }
```

where I'm going wrong? Please help me..

Comment: I would also like to know what exactly "m_FullPath" is??

Comment: Is your application OOB? You cannot get the isolated storage full path without your application being Out Of Browser - I've tried many times and failed!

Comment: @DNKROZ: You are right. I have come to the same conclusion after searching for it. But in silverlight 5, you can get access to local file system even if your application is running inside browser. But for that you need to provide elevated trust for your application. Please refer this [MSDN link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Ah right, i came across this once but didn't look into it any further when i saw it involved certificates, i will read into it further - thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

For those that have Elevated Permissions (especially in browser) I have come up with a semi-functional solution to determine the path. Unfortunately, if you switch from dev to live you will see a different folder path, so you have to include it here, also you should add a check for which version you are running (dev or live) via a passed in page parameter or the host url or so

```
private string GetProfilePath() {
var fullname = string.Empty;
try
{
    // ReSharper disable IdentifierTypo
    // ReSharper disable CommentTypo
    var profilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    profilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(profilePath);
    profilePath = Path.Combine(profilePath, @"LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is");
    //profilePath = Path.Combine(profilePath, IsoPathStaging + "\\");
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(profilePath); // C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is --constant
    var dirs = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories();
    // ReSharper disable PossibleMultipleEnumeration
    fullname = "1: " + dirs.First().FullName;
    dirs = dirs.First().EnumerateDirectories(); // \ir5ffeej.4of --random
    fullname = "2: " + dirs.First().FullName;
    dirs = dirs.First().EnumerateDirectories(); // \lfab1wva.xmb --random
    fullname = "3: " + dirs.First().FullName;
    dirs = dirs.First().EnumerateDirectories(); // \1 --constant
    fullname = "4: " + dirs.First().FullName;
    dirs = dirs.Where(d => d.Name == "s"); // \s --constant
    fullname = "5: " + dirs.First().FullName;
    var dirs2 = dirs.First().EnumerateDirectories()
        .Where(d => d.Name == "sbudlbc2oqx0eo0odi5nzpo2qppp3zmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").ToList(); // \<dev dir> --constant-ish
    if (!dirs2.Any())
    {
        dirs2 = dirs.First().EnumerateDirectories()
            .Where(d => d.Name == "2gbsxl5no1wzqebnzbj2wglhi33za1rxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").ToList(); // \<live dir> --constant-ish
    }
    if (!dirs2.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to locate silverlight storage");
    }
    fullname = "6: " + dirs2.First().FullName;
    dirs = dirs2.First().EnumerateDirectories().Where(d => d.Name == "f"); // \f --constant
    fullname = "7: " + dirs.First().FullName;
    var dir = dirs.First(); // final
    fullname = dir.FullName;
    // ReSharper restore CommentTypo
    // ReSharper restore PossibleMultipleEnumeration
    return fullname;
    // ReSharper restore IdentifierTypo
}
catch (NotSupportedException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Failed to run (Not Supported):"
        + Environment.NewLine + fullname
        + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message,
        messageBoxTitle,
        MessageBoxButton.OK);
    CheckElevatedPermissions();
    return string.Empty;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Failed to run:"
        + Environment.NewLine + fullname
        + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message,
        messageBoxTitle,
        MessageBoxButton.OK);
    return string.Empty;
}
}
```

Again, you must have elevated rights for this to work, later I would use this path to locate a file for some other use:

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(GetProfilePath(), FileName);
Run(fullPath.Replace("\\\\", "\\"));

private static void Run(string fullPath)
{
    try
    {
        CheckElevatedPermissions();
        var shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
        shell.Run("\"" + fullPath + "\"");
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Failed to run (Not Supported):"
            + Environment.NewLine + fullPath
            + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message,
            messageBoxTitle,
            MessageBoxButton.OK);
        CheckElevatedPermissions();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Failed to run:"
            + Environment.NewLine + fullPath
            + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message,
            messageBoxTitle,
            MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: After I wrote this, I went back and designed a different solution based on placing a file that had no contents but a filename that was a time-stamp. I would then search all the silverlight folders on that base path for the correct timestamp file and then grab the parent folder.